# Retrieve the number of opened file descriptors using the Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, file-descriptor

I would like to know how many file descriptors have I opened in my C++ application. Can this be done using  Windows API function?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "file descriptors"? File opened by e.g. `fopen` or `_open`? C++ file streams? WIN32 `OpenFile` handles?

Comment: Furthermore, any answer you calculate will be instantly wrong because another thread can open or close a handle before you can act on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask each handle in the process using [GetFileType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
      DWORD type_char = 0, 
      type_disk = 0, 
      type_pipe = 0, 
      type_remote = 0, 
      type_unknown = 0,
      handles_count = 0;

GetProcessHandleCount(GetCurrentProcess(), &handles_count);
handles_count *= 4;
for (DWORD handle = 0x4; handle < handles_count; handle += 4) {
    switch (GetFileType((HANDLE)handle)){
        case FILE_TYPE_CHAR:
            type_char++;
            break;
        case FILE_TYPE_DISK:
            type_disk++;
            break;
        case FILE_TYPE_PIPE: 
            type_pipe++;
            break;
        case FILE_TYPE_REMOTE: 
            type_remote++;
            break;
        case FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
            if (GetLastError() == NO_ERROR) type_unknown++;
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: In the sequence of handles  some may be invalid/closed which is not counted by handles_count, so the program is need to be modified to continue the loop counting valid handles. For some of valid handles GetFileType returns error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after checking open handles then you can the [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) utility from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default).