# How to find count of open file descriptors for current process in Windows and Linux?

Tags: c, linux, windows, file-descriptor

I want to know, how can I find number of open file descriptor in Windows OS. For Linux I know we can find it from:

```
# cd /proc/<pid of process>/fd
#ls -l | wc -l
```

But the above approach will not work for other platform like Windows.

Is there any api which I can use in C-code, to find current open file descriptor for a process?

Comment: Windows doesn't use file descriptors on the kernel layer, it uses handles. The handles are effectively 32-bit ids, probably they were once pointers. The Windows C library converts them to file descriptors. I don't know the deeper details, but probably the windows C library should you check, which is part of the visual studio. Btw, your question title wants to find an open file descriptor, but your question body gives an example to get the list of the file descriptors. I suggest to make these urgently in synchron - the close vote review is quite vehement on the site.

Comment: You can use Process Explorer from Windows SysInternals to view handles belonging to a process. There is a less featured command-line program called "handle", also from SysInternals.

Comment: @peterh changed problem title

Comment: @IanAbbott: can you please mention in detail

Comment: As I checked handle sysinternal needs to be installed separately, is there any way to get open file handle for current process in windows without installing anything else.

Comment: Also, I found one thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357961/retrieve-the-number-of-opened-file-descriptors-using-the-windows-api

I think GetProcessHandleCount() this sould solve my issue

Comment: On unix you can use /proc/self no need to get your own pid